# Event-handling using templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, event-handling, variadic-templates

I have been playing around with the new C++11 standard lately and decided to create a basic event-handling system. The code below provides a small example of my current implementation.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Event>
class EventBroadcaster
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const Event&)> Connection;

    void connect(Connection&& connection)
    {
        connections.push_back(std::move(connection));
    }

    void signal(const Event& event)
    {
        for (const auto& connection : connections)
        {
            connection(event);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Connection> connections;
};

struct MouseMotion
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

class Input : public EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>
{
public:
    void process()
    {
        MouseMotion mouseMotion;
        mouseMotion.x = 10;
        mouseMotion.y = 20;
        signal(mouseMotion);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    Input input;

    input.connect([&](const MouseMotion& e){
        x += e.x;
        y += e.y;
    });

    input.process();

    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl; // Output: 10,20

    return 0;
}
```

The above solution does work quite nicely if the `Input` class would only broadcast a single event. There might however be the case that the `Input` class would want to be able to send `KeyPress` events besides just `MouseMotion` events.

I thought about using multiple inheritance. Making `Input` inherit both `EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>` and `EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>`. This results in compiler errors warning of ambiguous functions. The solution provided in the following answer [Multiple Inheritance Template Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3360909/1175300) does work for the protected `signal` function, but not for the public `connect` function called outside the `Input` class.

Besides multiple inheritance I wondered if variadic-templates could help my with my problem. I have looked at (partial) template specialization and unpacking variadic-templates. But have been unable to come with an (elegant) solution.

What would be the best way to support multiple event types?

Comment: How come the solution you linked does not work for `connect()`?

Comment: Adding the following to the Input class doesn't work:`using EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>::signal;
using EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>::signal;
using EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>::connect;
using EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>::connect;` It does however work for MouseMotion events after I just remove the `using EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>::connect;` line. But than remains the problem of not being able to connect KeyPress events.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `connections.push_back(std::move(connection));` would be more efficient, and calling the function can be just `connection(event)` without the extra parentheses

Comment: @JonathanWakely Why not `emplace_back()`?

Comment: @user1095108, `push_back` is fewer characters to type and there's no advantage to `emplace_back` in this case so why use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make `EventBroadcaster<T>` an implementation detail, and instead expose `EventBroadcasters<Ts...>`.

`EventBroadcasters<Ts...>` owns `EventBroadcaster<Ts>...` has template methods `connect<U>` and `signal<U>`, and forwards these to the `EventBroadcaster<U>`.  This should fail to compile if `U` is not in `Ts...`.

So now you `signal(mouseMotion)`, which resolves to `signal<MouseMotion>(mouseMotion)`, which connects through to the correct broadcaster.

When you `connect` to listen, similarly so long as you are using the right kind of `std::function` things work.  And if not, you can just pass in the type of the `Event` you are listening for.

There are ways to make it even more magical, and enable full-on proper overload resolution that you'd want, but that gets really tricky.  Ie, you instrument up `connect` to do SFINAE and manually dispatch the passed in lambda (by examining its `operator()`) to the correct `std::function` override.  However, simply being able to say `connect<MouseMotion>([&](MouseMotion m){...})` should be an improvement.

(SFINAE technique would consist of checking which `std::function` type out of a list can be constructed from your passed in `U`, and if there is one unique such, using that one.  Also, check if `U` is such a `std::function` (or a cv variant of such).  It isn't ridiculously hard, but it is very messy looking, and in my experience most people don't like the type-spew and prefer to just specify `<MouseMotion>`.)

**UPDATE:**

The following code block provides an implementation of this answer.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename Event>
    class EventBroadcaster
    {
    public:
        typedef std::function<void(const Event&)> Connection;

        void connect(Connection&& connection)
        {
            connections.push_back(std::move(connection));
        }

        void signal(const Event& event)
        {
            for (const auto& connection : connections)
            {
                connection(event);
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<Connection> connections;
    };

   template <typename T> struct traits
       : public traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

   template <typename C, typename R, typename A>
   struct traits<R(C::*)(const A&) const>
   {
       typedef A type;
   };
}

template <typename... Events>
class EventBroadcaster
   : detail::EventBroadcaster<Events>...
{
public:
    template <typename Connection>
    void connect(Connection&& connection)
    {
        typedef typename detail::traits<Connection>::type Event;
        detail::EventBroadcaster<Event>& impl = *this;
        impl.connect(std::move(connection));
    }

    template <typename Event>
    void signal(const Event& event)
    {
        detail::EventBroadcaster<Event>& impl = *this;
        impl.signal(event);
    }

    virtual void processEvents() = 0;
};

struct MouseMotion
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

struct KeyPress
{
    char c;
};

class Input
    : public EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion, KeyPress>
{
public:
    void processEvents()
    {
        MouseMotion mouseMotion;
        mouseMotion.x = 10;
        mouseMotion.y = 20;
        signal(mouseMotion);

        KeyPress keyPress;
        keyPress.c = 'a';
        signal(keyPress);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char c = '~';

    Input input;

    input.connect([&](const MouseMotion& e){
        x += e.x;
        y += e.y;
    });

    input.connect([&](const KeyPress& e){
        c = e.c;
    });

    input.processEvents();

    std::cout << c << " " << x << "," << y << std::endl; // Output: a 10,20

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is OK to you, you can solve this problem by adding the `using` directives for `KeyPress` in your `Input` class and store your lambda in a `std::function<>` object rather than using `auto`:

```
class Input :
    public EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>,
    public EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>
{
public:
    using EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>::signal;
    using EventBroadcaster<MouseMotion>::connect;

    // ADD THESE!
    using EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>::signal;
    using EventBroadcaster<KeyPress>::connect;

    Input() {}
    virtual ~Input() {}
    void process()
    {
        MouseMotion mouseMotion;
        mouseMotion.x = 10;
        mouseMotion.y = 20;
        signal(mouseMotion);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Input input;

    int myX = 0;
    int myY = 0;

    // STORE THE LAMBDA IN A function<> OBJECT:
    std::function<void(const MouseMotion&)> onMouseMotion = [&](const MouseMotion& e){
        myX += e.x;
        myY += e.y;
    };

    // THIS WILL NOT BE AMBIGUOUS:
    input.connect(onMouseMotion);

    input.process();
    std::cout << myX << "," << myY << std::endl; // Output: 10,20

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

What follows is an improvement of the above solution that does not require wrapping the lambda handler in an `std::function` object. It is enough to change the definition of the `connect` method as follows, and let SFINAE take care of ruling out the inappropriate overloads:

```
template<typename F>
void connect(F connection, decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Event>()))* = nullptr)
{
    connections.push_back(connection);
}
```

It is now possible to call `connect()` this way:

```
input.connect([&](const MouseMotion& e){
    myX += e.x;
    myY += e.y;
    });

input.connect([&](const KeyPress& e){
    std::cout << e.c;
    });
```

Comment: Wrapping the lambda in a function object does indeed remove the ambiguous compiler errors. Instead the compiler gives me the following errors: `no match for call to (std::function<void(const MouseMotion&)>) (const KeyPress&)` and `no match for call to (std::function<void(const KeyPress&)>) (const MouseMotion&)`. Somehow mixing KeyPress and MouseMotion.

Comment: @Daniel: [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2CXJqe$0) works for me. Could you show the code you're trying?

Comment: Found the problem. I am passing Connection to connect using an rvalue reference, which seems to cause the errors. I should read some more about them before actually using them. :)

Comment: @Daniel: OK, glad it works. If this solves your problem, please consider accepting this answer. If it doesn't, let me know and I'll try to work on it a bit more :-)

Comment: I'd like to be able to call connect like `input.connect([&](const MouseMotion& e){myX += e.x;myY += e.y;});`. Using a std::function to wrap the lambda is not very friendly in use. I'm not really sure on how to do this.

Comment: @Daniel: What is your compiler?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm afraid GCC 4.7.2 has a bug that makes it hard to create an easy workaround. I have a solution that [works on Clang 3.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SM5m1$8) (and on ICC 13.0.1 as well), but GCC throws a compilation error when I try it. I believe it is a bug.

Comment: @Daniel: I reworked the solution and this compiles with GCC 4.7.2 (see the update to the answer). Please check it out.