# virtual method behaves differently with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, name-lookup, class-members

why this works

```
struct Base {
    virtual void visit(const A &) { };
    virtual void visit(const B &) { };
}
```

and this complains about ambiguity when calling visit method

```
template< typename T >
struct X {
    virtual void visit(const T &) { };
};

struct Base: X< A >, X< B > { };
```

this also shows the same problem:

```
struct Y {
   virtual void visit(const A &) { };
};

struct Z {
    virtual void visit(const B &) { };
};

struct Base: Z, Y { };
```

somehow it looks like the multiple inheritance messes with the virtual function signatures...

*with gcc version 4.8.0 20130411 (prerelease)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple-inheritance-template-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360892/multiple-inheritance-template-class)

Comment: Side note: You do not need `;` after a `}` ending a function body as in `virtual void visit(const A &) { };` and this is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Here virtual-ness is irrelevant and the fact 2 base classes are template classes is irrelevant. A simpler code with the same issue is:

```
struct A {
   void f(const A &) { }
};

struct B {
    void f(const B &) { }
};

struct Der: A,B { };
```

Here `Der` has two inherited members: `A::f(const A &)` and `B::f(const B &)`; they can be invoked this way:

```
Der d;
d.A::f(d);
d.B::f(d);
```

but *not* this way:

```
d.f((A&)d); // error: ambiguous name lookup
d.f((B&)d); // error: ambiguous name lookup
```

Member function overloading resolution does *not* work the way you think (find both `f` then keep the one which has a compatible argument list).

In C++, *member* name-lookup finds all non-hidden member declarations with a given name, so here it finds `A::f(const A &)` and `B::f(const B &)`, then it fails immediately if these members are not declared in the same class.

You can solve this problem by adding 2 declarations in the same class:

```
struct Der: A,B {
    using A::f; // imports A::f(const A &)
    using B::f; // imports B::f(const B &)
};
```

Then you can do:

```
Der d;
d.f((A&)d); // OK: Der::f(&A)
```

Remember: this is purely a member name-lookup ambiguity.