# How to call inherited class's functions in templated class

Tags: c++, templates

If a class inherits multiple classes with the same function, how does it call each inherited class's function without manually specific each class?

Example code as below:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface1() = default;
    void foo()
    {
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
};

class Interface2
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface2() = default;
    void foo()
    {
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
};

class ObjectWithoutTemplate : public Interface1, Interface2
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        // How do I write the code to call each InterfaceX's foo() here
        // without manually specify each class?
        Interface1::foo();
        Interface2::foo();
        // The desired code looke like
        // for each interface in Interfaces {
        //     interface::foo()
        // }
    }
};

template <class... Interfaces>
class ObjectWithTemplate : Interfaces...
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        // It does not compile if the template does not inherit Interface[1|2]
        Interface1::foo();
        Interface2::foo();
        // The desired code looke like
        // for each interface in Interfaces {
        //     interface::foo()
        // }
    }
};
int main()
{
    ObjectWithoutTemplate objWithout;
    ObjectWithTemplate<Interface1, Interface2> objWith;
    objWithout.foo();
    objWith.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

For `ObjectWithoutTemplate`, I could call interfaces' `foo()` by manually specifying the interface:

```
    Interface1::foo();
    Interface2::foo();
```

But for `ObjectWithTemplate`'s `foo()`, how do I write the code to call each inherited interfaces' `foo()`, considering there will be `Interface3`, `Interface4` as well.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360892/multiple-inheritance-template-class

Comment: @ThePhilomath That solves a different problem (calling one of the base class's functions that only differ by parameters).

Comment: You can't. You have to specify the base class in some way. An alternative is `Interface1* i1 = this; i1->foo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Folding expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) from C++17 helps here:

```
template <class... Interfaces>
class ObjectWithTemplate : public Interfaces...
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        (Interfaces::foo(), ...);
    }
};
```

For C++11/C++14 version, it can also be done but is more verbose.

Comment: Wow, this is great!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't want any of the bases to be repeated (and none of the bases inherit from each other) you can do this;

```
template <class FirstInterface, class... Interfaces>
class ObjectWithTemplate : public FirstInterface, public ObjectWithTemplate<Interfaces...>
{
   public:
      void foo()
      {
          FirstInterface::foo();
          ObjectWithTemplate<Interfaces...>::foo();
      };
};

// partial specialisation
template<class LastInterface> 
class ObjectWithTemplate<LastInterface> : public LastInterface
{
    public:
       void foo()
       {
           LastInterface::foo();
       };
};
```

An object of type

```
ObjectWithTemplate<Interface1, Interface2> object;
```

actually has `Interface1` and `ObjectWithTemplate<Interface2>` as base classes.  `ObjectWithTemplate<Interface2>`, in turn, has `Interface2` as a base class.

If you repeat bases, or use two bases that share another base such as

```
ObjectWithTemplate<Interface1, Interface1> object;

ObjectWithTemplate<Interface1, SomethingDerivedFromInterface1> object2;
```

then the code will not compile due to ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, it works and compares to my own answer, it does not require extra space of `std::tuple`! Could you kindly check my answer (which is less code) and perhaps improves it to make it not using `std::tuple`?

Comment: Recursion can be avoided with folding expression.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Generating one class member per variadic template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941661/generating-one-class-member-per-variadic-template-argument), using `std::tuple<>` makes it work.

It's not perfect because it increases the binary size, but it works cleanly.

```
template <class... Interfaces>
class ObjectWithTemplate : public Interfaces...
{
  public:
    std::tuple<Interfaces...> interfaces;

    void foo()
    {
        // The size becomes 8 * num-of-inherited-classes
        printf("sizeof(interfaces)=%zu\n", sizeof(interfaces));
        std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {
            (static_cast<decltype(args)>(*this).foo(), ...);
            },
            interfaces);
    }
};
```

Comment: As you already use folding expression, you might use directly with bases, see my answer.