# Member functions ambiguity with multiple inheritance templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am public deriving two instances of class template 'Area', one int and another char into an separate class 'Rectangle'.

```
template<class T>
class Area {
  public:
    T a;
    T getArea() { return a; }
    void setArea(T t) { a = t; }
};  

class Rectangle : public Area<int>, public Area<char> {
};  

int main() {
  Rectangle a;
  a.setArea(1);
  std::cout << a.getArea() << std::endl;
  Rectangle b;
  b.setArea('c');
  std::cout << b.getArea() << std::endl;
}
```

And I see ambiguity with setArea and getArea. Why is that so? I thought after public Area, public Area there would be two definitions of setArea. First, void setArea(int) and another void setArea(char). Please correct me if I am wrong. And If I am correct, why the ambiguity?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360892/multiple-inheritance-template-class

Comment: @AzamBham I tried using statements already. That would not work. Where do put using statements?

Comment: The compiler can't infer automatically which version of `a.getArea()` you meant to call. Try helping it: `std::cout << a.Area<char>::getArea() << std::endl;`

Comment: @MihaiTodor, Thanks for coming back. That also I tried and it did not work too.

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/0WaMIo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bring the name `setArea` from both the base classes into the derived class with `using` statements:

```
class Rectangle : public Area<int>, public Area<char> {
  using Area<int>::setArea;
  using Area<char>::setArea;
};
```

the compiler will be able to call the right `setArea`.

This will not work for `getArea` as the 2 functions differ only in their return type. You will have to distinguish between them at the call site:

```
std::cout << a.Area<int>::getArea() << std::endl;
```